# Google Cloud Translate V3 Java - PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud IAM permission 'cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict' denied

Tags: java, google-translate, google-translation-api

I have one project in google cloud, already using speech APIs successfully.
I am the only user and I have Owner permissions over the service.
My account is connected to billing.
The environment credentials is set and working properly with other services.
I'm using Java SDK v3 (advanced translation).

When running translation in java I get `PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud IAM permission 'cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict' denied`.

```
try (TranslationServiceClient client = TranslationServiceClient.create()) {

            // projects/MY_PROJECT_ID/locations/global
            LocationName parent = LocationName.of("MY_PROJECT_ID", "global");

            // projects/MY_PROJECT_ID/locations/global/models/general/base
            String model = parent.toString() +  "/models/general/base";
            
            TranslateTextRequest request =
                    TranslateTextRequest.newBuilder()
                            .setParent(parent.toString())
                            .setMimeType("text/plain")
                            .setSourceLanguageCode("he")
                            .setTargetLanguageCode("en")
                            .setModel(model)
                            .addContents(source)
                            .build();

            TranslateTextResponse response = client.translateText(request);

            for (Translation translation : response.getTranslationsList()) {
                System.out.printf("Translated text: %s\n", translation.getTranslatedText());
            }
        }
```

Please advise :)

Comment: So have you assigned the specific IAM roles to the account you're trying to use? See https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/intro-to-v3#iam

Comment: Resolved - I had to create a new service account in the project, and then select the Translation API Admin role. Thanks @JonSkeet

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to do this steps:

1. You need to create a service account in https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts
   Will be generated Email address for this account. Copy it.
2. Make sure you have billing created and you have enabled the Google Translation API
3. Next, you need to grant access rights to your new service account.
   IAM -> GRANT ACCESS -> Add Principle (this is your already copied email address from first step) -> Select a role (need to find "Cloud Translation API Admin")

Rerun your application.